# Calculating Price Based Off Price Break Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have an orders table and a price break table.  If an itemcode exists in the price break table then the price is reduced based on the quantity.  I am not sure of what the syntax would be for a conditional like this, so I am going to seek assistance.  This is sample DDL and a query that I started on with a case statement but not sure how to finish it off

```
 DECLARE @Parent TABLE
(
  itemname VARCHAR(100),
  itemprice FLOAT,
  itemqty INT
)

 DECLARE @Exceptions TABLE
(
  itemname VARCHAR(100),
  qtyordered VARCHAR(10),
  itemrpice FLOAT
)

 INSERT INTO @Parent ( itemname, itemprice, itemqty )
            VALUES  (  'rr11',   0.00 ,     10 ),
                    (  'rr11',   0.00 ,     5 ),
                    (  'rr11',   0.00 ,     22 ),
                    (  'mc22',   15.00,     5 )

 INSERT INTO @Exceptions ( itemname, qtyordered, itemrpice )
            VALUES      (  'rr11',  '1-5' ,     15.50 ),
                        (  'rr11',  '6-10',     11.00 ),
                        (  'rr11',  '>11' ,     17.00 )
Select
itemname
,case when itemprice IN (Select itemrpice from @Exceptions) Then 
--compare the quantities to gather the pricing info
itemqty
FROM @Parent
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach this using a SQL JOIN that joins both tables on the item, and the appropriate discount.

```
DECLARE @Parent TABLE 
(
    ItemName varchar(100) NOT NULL
    , ItemPrice decimal(18,4) NOT NULL
    , ItemQuantity int NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @Exceptions TABLE
(
    ItemName varchar(100) NOT NULL
    , MinQuantityOrdered int NOT NULL
    , MaxQuantityOrdered int NOT NULL
    , ItemPrice decimal(18,4) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Parent (ItemName, ItemPrice, ItemQuantity) 
VALUES ('rr11', 999999.99, 10)
    , ('rr11', 999999.99, 5)
    , ('rr11', 999999.99, 22)
    , ('mc22', 15.00, 5)

INSERT INTO @Exceptions (ItemName, MinQuantityOrdered, MaxQuantityOrdered, ItemPrice) 
VALUES ('rr11', 1, 5, 15.50)
    , ('rr11', 6, 10, 11.00)
    , ('rr11', 11, 999999, 17.00);

SELECT p.ItemName
    , p.ItemQuantity
    , AdjustedPrice = ISNULL(e.ItemPrice, p.ItemPrice)
    , AdjustedTotal = p.ItemQuantity * ISNULL(e.ItemPrice, p.ItemPrice)
FROM @Parent p
    LEFT JOIN @Exceptions e ON p.itemname = e.itemname 
        AND p.ItemQuantity >= e.MinQuantityOrdered 
        AND p.ItemQuantity <= e.MaxQuantityOrdered;
```

The results:

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| ItemName | ItemQuantity | AdjustedPrice | AdjustedTotal |
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| rr11     |           10 |       11.0000 |      110.0000 |
| rr11     |            5 |       15.5000 |       77.5000 |
| rr11     |           22 |       17.0000 |      374.0000 |
| mc22     |            5 |       15.0000 |       75.0000 |
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
```

You'll notice in the example above, I have arbitrarily chosen the value `999999.00` as the maximum price for item `rr11` in the `@Parent` table.  That was only because you chose to use `0.00` for the default price of the item.  If you use `0.00` for a default price, and then forget to create an entry in the `@Exceptions` table for that item, people will buy as many of those items as they can order since they will be essentially free.  I used `999999` as the maximum quantity for a discount in the `@Exceptions` table since you need to choose some maximum number for the `MaxQuantityOrdered` column, and 999999 seems like a fairly high number of items to order.  If you believe you'll sell a million or more items in one order, by all means increase that.  Since the quantity columns are `int` data types, the maximum you could specify would be 2147483647, which is a lot.

A couple of nit-picky things I noticed:

1. Use the correct case, for both keywords, data types, and column names.

   - keywords should be in ALL CAPS, that is how they are shown in the documentation.
   - data types should be lower-case since that is how they are listed in `sys.types`
   - column names should be camel case, or in the very least not alllowercapscrammedtogether.  Just for sanity of the reader.
2. You are putting quotes around numeric values.  Don't.
3. You should use a numeric range for values that are numeric.  i.e. Don't use a character column like `0 - 15` for the range of quantities, use two columns, `MinValue` and `MaxValue` with `0` and `15`.
4. This one is a bit subjective, and many people won't agree fully with me.  Don't use a char value such as `ItemName` as the key to join rows between tables unless you are certain those values will not change.  Use a surrogate integer key to uniquely identify each item.  Name it `ItemID`.  Then if you ever need to correct the spelling of an item, you won't need to update every reference to that item in the database.  Yes, you can use relational integrity to cascade those changes throughout all referenced tables, but if you just use a surrogate key from the start, you'll never have to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You should break the quantity ordered into two columns or at least one integer column (but I like two).  MinQuantity and MaxQuantity.  Note I don't usually allow for abbreviations in tables or columns, but I'll make exceptions if it's universally accepted like Min and Max.  Second, name your table appropriately, something like PriceBreak is more descriptive in my opinion than Exception (that could mean anything).

Once we have proper table names, column names and data types, then the solution becomes much easier.  You will use the itemname and itemquantity to join to the proper row (itemquantity between minquantity and maxquantity).  One of the reasons that it's a good idea to name everything well is that the code becomes self documenting and is easier to create and troubleshoot.  In that scenario, you won't even need a case statement, just a LEFT JOIN and an ISNULL.

```
DECLARE @Order TABLE 
(
    itemname            varchar(100)
    ,itemprice          money
    ,QuantityOrdered    int
)

DECLARE @PriceBreak TABLE
(
    itemname        varchar(100)
    ,MinQuantity    int
    ,MaxQuantity    int
    ,itemprice      money
)

INSERT INTO @Order (itemname, itemprice, QuantityOrdered) 
VALUES
     ('rr11', '0.00', 10)
    ,('rr11', '0.00', 5)
    ,('rr11', '0.00', 22)
    ,('mc22', '15.00', 5)

INSERT INTO @PriceBreak (itemname, MinQuantity, MaxQuantity, itemprice) 
VALUES
     ('rr11', 1,5, '15.50')
    ,('rr11', 6,10, '11.00')
    ,('rr11', 11,99999, '17.00')

SELECT
    O.itemname
    ,ISNULL(PB.ItemPrice, O.itemprice) ItemPrice
    ,QuantityOrdered
    ,ISNULL(PB.ItemPrice, O.itemprice) * QuantityOrdered
FROM 
    @Order O
    LEFT JOIN @PriceBreak PB ON O.itemname = PB.itemname AND O.QuantityOrdered BETWEEN PB.MinQuantity and PB.MaxQuantity
```